# Getter/Setter problem in C#

Tags: c#, setter

I am doing

```
static bool isWorking
    {
        get { return _isWorking; }
        set {
            myform.treeView1.Enabled = !value;
            _isWorking = value;
        }
    }
```

and stepping through the debugger shows it stops at the first set line.
After trying this line instead

```
set { myform.treeView1.Enabled = !(_isWorking = value); }
```

I see that isWorking  is set but myform.treeView1.Enabled is not. Whats going on?

Comment: the debugger stops = you get an exception?

Comment: Is `myform` static? I assume `_isWorking` is static as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What do you mean by "the debugger shows it stops"? Is it possibly that `myform` is null, or `myform.treeView1` is null?

I can't remember the *exact* evaluation order in this case, but it could explain the symptoms you're describing. Knowing why the debugger "stops" is crucial though. Another possibility is that you're trying to access the UI from a non-UI thread, which would prevent the assignment to `Enabled` from working properly.

Oh, and please don't use your second version - assignment as a side-effect is very, very rarely a good idea. The only idiomatic use I know is when looping with IO:

```
string line;
while ( (line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
```

and I only consider that acceptable because it's reasonably common. In this case it really looks like you *could* mean "==" instead of "=".

Comment: Your correct, i am trying to access UI in a non UI thread. I switch the order and _isWorking is properly set. I never notice this until you mention UI in non UI thread -> A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll.

Answer (score -2):

Because (_isWorking = value) returns always true. If you would write:

```
myform.treeView1.Enabled = !(_isWorking == value);
```

It works like: if isWorking is equal to value then Disable treeView. But in you case - no

Comment: No, (_isWorking = value) assigns value to _isWorking and returns value (or _isWorking, which is the same thing now), so if value is false, (_isWorking = value) return false.